# Php max_input_vars prevents attribute options savign in M2

Tags: php, magento, memory, magento2

**Magento 2.2.1. PHP 7.0.26 Nginx**

After 2 days struggling around with attribute options in M2, I found out where the problem was.

I have several custom dropdown attributes with hundreds of options. I created them via REST API and everything was fine, all options created and all values correct. The problem arose as soon as I tried to update/save these attribute again, changing any value, like for example, the "Is filterable".

What happened was that Magento says that the attribute is saved, but in fact, in the above mentioned case, the "use in layered navigation" was simply set to "no".

Nothing in log files, nothing anywhere.

I found out is a PHP memory problem and that I should have increased `max_input_vars` value in php.ini, from 1000 to something else.

I arrived, to try, to 10000000 but I managed to save only 720 options, whereas I need to save at least 1300 options and this is not said to be the limit over time.

Do you have any clue about how to properly set this value?
Or what other values?

I also increased

```
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 600
post_max_size = 512M
```